# How to get Substring from Filename in Unix shellscripting

Tags: linux, shell

I want a shell script to get `MMDDYYYY` from the file with a name as mentioned below file

```
linuxbox.23566.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS.zip
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `bash` string functions:

```
for file in *.zip; do 
    file="${file%.*}"
    file="${file##*.}"
    echo "${file:0:8}"
done
```

#### Explaination:

- `file="${file%.*}"`: Gets rid of the extension and stores the new name in `file` variable
- `file="${file##*.}"`: Gets rid of the longest match from beginning and stores the name in `file` variable
- `echo "${file:0:8}"`: `echoes` the first 8 characters of whats left.

#### Demo:

```
$ ls
linuxbox.23566.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS.zip
$ for file in *; do file="${file%.*}"; file="${file##*.}"; echo "${file:0:8}"; done
MMDDYYYY
```

Answer (score 1):

With `cut`:

```
$ cut -d. -f3 <<< "linuxbox.23566.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS.zip" | cut -c-8
MMDDYYYY
```

Because the first part is returning:

```
$ cut -d. -f3 <<< "linuxbox.23566.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS.zip"
MMDDYYYYHHMMSS
```

And then it gets the first 8 chars.

Comment: the above is working in terminal. If i'm adding this in shell scripting this is not working. Can you provide shell script for the above command

Comment: What did you exactly try? Please update your question showing what you did.